# ASPNETZERO - Validation issue

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

After my upgrade to ASPNETZERO V4.X I am experiencing strange validation errors across multiple flavors of the ASPNETZERO/ABP templates. I am working on multiple projects and I am using the .NET MVC5 template, .NET Core MVC template and the ABP Open source template with BSB admin theme. I am getting this same validation message in all these different projects. Here is an example.

[Chrome console showing validation error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5HAoiVVXzY7Z0JTSjV6MW1YVFU/view?usp=sharing)

[Chrome console showing values sent to app service](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5HAoiVVXzY7Y0tPWjFXT3JKRkE/view?usp=sharing)

[Another error example from ABP open source version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5HAoiVVXzY7U2QxblhTTGFhMnc/view?usp=sharing)

Does anyone know how I can find the root cause of this error. How do I debug the ABP validation code to find the root cause of this error?
Also, sometimes the error does not come up and the app service calls execute normally. But then you try the exact same one again, a minute later and it fails!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So today, I was able to find an error message getting logged in the internal log files. I found the error below logged.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Decimal'. Path 'Width', line 1, position 99. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Null object cannot be converted to a value type.
>      at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)

This was being reported on one of my decimal properties (Width) that is optional and not required. I changed the property to accept null with the code below.

> decimal?

After that change, it resolved the validation error on one of my entities. I will check if the other projects have the same issue.